# How do I craft in Fallout: New Vegas?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

In Fallout: New Vegas, how do I craft weapons or items I find with the random loot all over buildings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need two things:

- Schematics
- A Workbench

Once you have all the required components that a schematic requires, you will then be able to create that item on a workbench, which are commonly found in towns at the mechanic's, but they can be found throughout the wasteland.

[The wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Crafting) has all the necessary information you need to get crafting.